# Как обработать файл с пустыми строками?

Tags: c++, файлы, строки

В общем, вот в чем суть вопроса: есть файл, который я считываю и обрабатываю так, как надо по заданию. Но если в него вставить пустые строки, то выводит ошибку сегментации. Как с этим справиться?
 Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

struct Team
{
    string name;
    string result;
    int point;
};
void Delete_Empty_Line ();
int  input_count();
void sort(Team * ,int);
Team* input(int);
void out(Team * ptr, int count);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Delete_Empty_Line ();
    int count = input_count();
    Team * ptr = input(count);
    sort(ptr, count);
    out(ptr, count);
    return 0;

}
void Delete_Empty_Line (void)
{
    ifstream FileInput ("premier_league.csv", ifstream::in);
    ofstream FileOutput ("premier_league1.csv", ofstream::out);
    assert(FileInput);
    assert(FileOutput);

    string String_Of_File;
    while (FileInput)
    {
        getline(FileInput, String_Of_File);
        if (!String_Of_File.empty())
        {
            FileOutput << String_Of_File;
            FileOutput << endl;
        }   
    }
    FileInput.close();
    FileOutput.close();
}

int input_count()
{
    int lines = 0;
    char s;
    FILE *fp = fopen("premier_league1.csv","r");
    while((s=getc(fp))!=EOF)
    {        
        if(s == '\n')
        lines++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return lines;    
}

Team* input(int count)
{
    ifstream f("premier_league1.csv");
    int* a =new int ;
    char*  b =new char ;
    f >> *a;f >>*b;
    Team *ptr = new Team[count];

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {

        ptr[i].point = 0;
        getline(f,ptr[i].name, ',');
        getline(f,ptr[i].result, '\n');

    }
    delete a; delete b;
    return ptr;
}

void sort(Team * ptr,int count)
{
    int match = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 40 ; j += 4)
        {
            if((int)ptr[i].result[j] > (int)ptr[i].result[j+2])
                ptr[i].point += 3;
            else if((int)ptr[i].result[j] == (int)ptr[i].result[j+2])
                ++ptr[i].point;
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < count -1 ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < count-i-1; j++)
        {
            if( ptr[j].point < ptr[j+1].point)
            {
                Team temp = ptr[j+1];
                ptr[j+1] = ptr[j];
                ptr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
 }

 void out(Team * ptr, int count)
 {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("results.csv", ios_base::out);
    for (int g = 0; g < count; g++)
     {
        fout << ptr[g].name << "," <<ptr[g].point << endl;
     }
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: а можете сделать [mcve]?

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Для начала - `fgetc()` не возвращает `char`.

Comment: счытвайте строку `fgets` потом парсите ее на предмет двух переменных `sscanf`

Comment: Что за безумная мешанина форматированного С++ I/O и неформатированного С I/O?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю, зачем вам вообще `int input_count()`, если посчитать число строк можно и в `input`?

Тем более что вы делаете что-то странное - считаете количество строк, затем считываете значение `a` из первой строки, создаете массив из `a` элементов, но читаете туда их `count` штук. Если у вас в первой строке точное число строк - то зачем маета с `input_count` вообще? Если нет - вы уверены, что `a` больше количества строк?

**Update**
Вобщем, я бы делал так:

```
struct Team
{
    string name;
    string result;
    int point;
    void getPoint();
};

void Team::getPoint()
{
    point = 0;
    string s = result;
    istringstream is(s);
    int me, other;
    char c;
    while(is >> me >> c >> other >> c)
    {
        point += (me > other);
    }
};

vector<Team> readFile(istream&in)
{
    vector<Team> tt;
    string s;
    getline(in,s);
    while(getline(in,s))
    {
        if (s.empty()) continue;
        size_t comma = s.find(',');
        assert(comma != string::npos);
        Team t;
        t.name = s.substr(0,comma-1);
        t.result = s.substr(comma+1);
        t.getPoint();
        tt.push_back(t);
    }
    return tt;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream in("premier_league.csv");
    vector<Team> t = readFile(in);
    sort(t.begin(),t.end(),[](const Team& a, const Team& b){ return a.point > b.point; });

    ofstream out("premier_league.csv.new");
    out << t.size() << "\n";
    for(const auto& x: t)
    {
        cout << x.name << "," << x.result << "\n";
        out << x.name << "," << x.result << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ага, там просто в файле первая строка это число с количеством строк и его надо пропустить. Для этого я поток перенаправил в 2 переменные . int<-число строк, char <- '\n'

Comment: Слушайте, дайте просто пару примеров - файл, где работает, и файл, где программа сыпется. Без этого говорить о чем-то - никакого толку...

Comment: Вот, исправил код..Как видите, я добавил функцию Delete_Empty_Line которая должна записывать в промежуточный файл текст без пустых строк. Однако, это всё не работает

Comment: Еще раз и медленно. Дайте образцы файлов, на которых происходят сбои, и с которыми работает нормально. Выложите где-нибудь и дайте ссылку...

Comment: https://github.com/ProgramEngineeringKPI/assignment-1-whiskey-spice-opensource
Вот ссылка на гитхаб. Там код и файл. Суть в том что должна работать функция удаления пустых строк, но при добавления таковых в файл все идет не по плану...(

Comment: Вы так и не пояснили, на каком файле падает. Вы просто добавляете пустые строки, не меняя первую??... И еще - вам обязательно нужно извращаться через массив, а не вектор, и сортировать самому, а не стандартным `sort`'ом?

Comment: Не меняя ни одной из строк. Просто в файле Enter нажимается и образовывается пустая строка

Comment: Вобщем, см. исправленный ответ. Переделывать под массив можно, но зачем?... Пустые строки обрабатывает. Непонятно, зачем отделять имя от результатов, но раз вам так хочется...

Comment: error: request for member ‘result’ in ‘x’, which is of non-clas
s type ‘const int’
         out << x.name << "," << x.result << "\n";
Таких ошибок где-то 20

Comment: http://ideone.com/pzlrSy - просто чтоб вы убедились в компилируемости. Я не виноват в старости вашего компилятора; в конце-концов, перепишите этот цикл сами...